# How is my Windows share not accessible after some time after being mounted at boot time?

Tags: windows, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have set up a Windows share to be mounted at boot time in `/etc/fstab` as follows:

```
//192.168.x.x/Google\040Drive   /home/myname/Google\040Drive cifs username=winuser,password=winpass,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0   0
```

Everything works right after boot. However, after some time (about 20 or more minutes) the mounted share is no longer accessible. Any attempt to access the share freezes the machine for about 5 minutes. Interestingly the mounted share then becomes available after the freeze. Can someone please help me understand what is going on?

Comment: I believe I am having this same problem - did you ever find a solution?